# Force template parameter to be a structure

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to do a base template class which parameter **T** must be a structure.

When I use a variable declared as being of type **T** (both in the template class as in a class that extends it defining **T**) GCC fails to compile it:

> GCC error: invalid use of incomplete
>   type ‘struct x'

Despite it working on VC I understand that it doesn't work because it shouldn't because the compiler isn't aware per the standard of the types that **T** represent.

Is there a way of making explicit that the type must be a structure?

What I'm doing in the code that works in VC is:

In the base class:

```
T* x
new T
sizeof(T)
```

In those that extend it:

```
x->member
```

Edit: I tried to take the relevant code. Here it is:

```
struct SomeStructureType
{
    int memberA;
    int memberB;
}

template <typename T> class Base
{

    protected:

        T* s;

        void addMember(string name,void* offset);

        Base()
        {
            s = new T;
        }

};

class Extender : public Base<SomeStructureType>
{
    public:

        Extender()
        {
            addMember("memberA",&s->memberA);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the source code of the class you are trying to write?

Comment: It sounds like you need 'typename T;', or maybe a forward class definition somewhere. But yes, you need to provide more code for a better diagnosis.

Comment: Added the code. It represents the relationship. The only thing missing is that in the base class I also need to get the size of T.

Comment: I may have a response (not a good one, though), but I want to make sure I understand what you want. You want to ensure that Base's T can ONLY be a POD type, is that correct? I'm guessing at what you mean by 'structure'

Comment: POD? I want Base's T to represent a structure. (Structure -> struct)

Comment: C++ doesn't differentiate between a struct and a class. The only difference is what access defaults to. A POD is a class/struct with only basic data types as members.

Comment: A struct *is* a class, in fact :) In any case, please post the real code. We can't help you if you don't trust us and show us the secret company codes that fail.

Comment: whenever you see an error that contains 'incomplete type' consider whether you have forward declared a type and are trying to use it without fully declaring the type.

Comment: *Why* do you need T to be a struct? What about a struct is it that you need, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (if not all) times the compiler complains about using an 'incomplete' type the problem resides in trying to use a forward declared class that has not been completely defined.

There are just so many things you can do with an incomplete type: define functions that take or return the type or references to it, define reference or pointer variables of that type... and others you cannot do: define variables of that type, create an object of the type, call any method or request any attribute from the type...

Answer (score 1):

The question in the title can be dismissed; C++ classes and structures cannot be distinguished other than by source code inspection.

The explanation is quite confusing. There's apparently a message about `struct x` yet the example code contains not a single `x`. That tells me that you're not careful about matching up errors and source code. Once you do that, you often don't need StackOverflow anymore - you'll see the problem yourself.

Comment: Translation of your post: "I can't help you so I will blame you". The names are obviously created to put here instead of putting the original names that mean nothing here

Comment: I just tweaked your posted code so it compiles (you omitted semicolons after your struct and class) and, um, it compiles fine for me.
Does the posted code exhibit the problem when you compile it?
Which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: @unknown, you should use your original names. It's too easy to have a typo somewhere. Nothing to be ashamed of.

Comment: You definitely should simplify your code before posting. Don't think I disagree with that. But do run the simplified code past your compiler. That step has two common outcomes: either the error is still there, or the error is gone. In the first case it's easier to understand the error in the simplified context. In the second case the error was actually in the part you removed, which means your assumption on the cause of the error was wrong and you can revisit those assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted other than two missing semicolons after class/struct definitions: http://codepad.org/yfbHa8sO

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't related to the fact that T must be a structure. The problem is in that one of the structures (that I'm using in my code but was not created by me) is said to be incomplete by gcc. Anyway, I removed the class that uses this structure and other classes compile with the same base class. So, is up to me to fix it and what I assumed about the problem was wrong.